# How to make a copy constructor for a linked list?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list

I worked through every function in this program, and I mostly get the concepts, but a copy constructor for the linked list has me stumped. I look at other answers regarding this but I don't get how to apply it to my situation.

I have three files, a test.cpp which holds main(), a IntList.cpp and a IntList.h.

test.cpp and IntList.h was provided by my professor, so its safe to assume theres no errors there. I just had to write IntList.cpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "IntList.h"


using namespace std;

IntList::IntList()
{
    head = NULL;
}

IntList::IntList(const IntList &)
{

    ???

}
```

Here's IntList.h. Let me know if you need test.cpp or the other functions in IntList.cpp.

```
// Specification file for the IntList class
#ifndef INTLIST_H
#define INTLIST_H

class IntList
{
private:
   // Declare a structure for the list
   struct ListNode
   {
      int value;
      struct ListNode *next;
   };

   ListNode *head;   // List head pointer

public:
   // Constructor
   IntList();

   // Copy constructor
   IntList(const IntList &);

   // Destructor
   ~IntList();

   // List operations
   void appendNode(int val);
   void removeByVal(int val);
   void displayList();
   void insertByPos(int val, int pos);
   void removeByPos(int pos);
   int search(int val);
};

#endif /* INTLIST_H_ */
```

EDIT:

I'm reading y'all's comments but it's just not clicking for me.

I tried to rewrite the code and it still wasn't making sense. Here's my attempt, I feel like I just don't get what this is supposed to look like.

```
IntList::IntList(const IntList &list) // maybe I name it list so I can refer to list.head?
{
     ListNode *nodePtr;
     nodePtr = list.head;

     if (nodePtr == NULL) // If the head of list is empty then theres no list to copy
     { 
          return;
     }

     while (nodePtr->next != 0) // Trying to iterate through the link
     {
          nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
     }

     ListNode *newNode;   
     nodePtr->next = newNode; 

     // ??? Confused again.
```

Here's my function for displayList()

```
void IntList::displayList()
{

    ListNode *nodePtr;

    nodePtr = head;

    while (nodePtr != NULL)
    {
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }

}
```

And here's my appendNode().

```
void IntList::appendNode(int val)
{

    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodePtr;

    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->value = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;


    if (!head)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {

        nodePtr = head;

        while (nodePtr->next != 0)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }

        nodePtr->next = newNode;

    }

}
```

Those made a lot of sense to me and I finished them pretty quickly. I'm not getting how to implement those ideas into the copy constructor. Can y'all help me figure out what I'm not getting?

Comment: Since you have implemented `displayList`, you know how to iterate over a list. Since you have implemented `appendNode`, you know how to add a node. So walk over the list passed as an argument to your copy constructor, and insert nodes with the same values into `this` list.

Comment: Remember how the linked list was built in the first place? One node at a time.  Enumerate that list, for each node, create one for your copy target, In your case you could enumerate the source, and for each node fire `appendNode` on the copy target (this).  Unrelated, contrary to your claim I find it nearly impossible to believe that a simple search of [`[cpp] linked list copy constructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+linked+list+copy+constructor) provided nothing useful.

Comment: I added an edit trying to explain my confusion better. I guess I'm not getting what needs to be done different with the copy constructor and what can remain the same as I had done it previous functions. @IgorTandetnik

Comment: I added an edit trying to explain my confusion better. I found other examples of copy constructors on here, but what's confusing me is that with my .h file I only have the *head and *next pointers to work with. Can I do something like list.head->next and repeat that or something? I'm not getting this concept and neither my textbook nor online examples seem to be alleviating it. I'm sure this stuff is simple though, I know. @WhozCraig

Answer (score 1):

Here you are

```
IntList::IntList( const IntList &list ) : head( nullptr )
{
    ListNode **new_node = &this->head;

    for ( auto current = list.head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        *new_node = new ListNode { current->value, nullptr };
        new_node = &( *new_node )->next; 
    }         
}
```

If you have difficulties to understand how to deal with pointers to pointers then I can suggest another constructor definition that does not use pointers to pointers.

```
IntList::IntList( const IntList &list ) : head( nullptr )
{
    if ( list.head != nullptr )
    {
        this->head = new ListNode { list.head->value, nullptr };

        for ( auto new_node = this->head, current = list.head->next;
              current != nullptr;
              new_node = new_node->next, current = current->next )
        {
            new_node->next = new ListNode { current->value, nullptr };
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does help a bit